# How to show a widget in a popover in flutter?

Tags: flutter, popover

[image]

I want to create a popover as shown in the image where I can add column to the popover and fill its children as required

I've tried [this](https://pub.dev/packages/popover) but I couldn't figure out how to achieve the objective.

Comment: you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal

Comment: i've tried to use it in my screen but i'm using multiple modal popup in my class and i can't get it to work it on more then one section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try the below code :

```
class PopoverExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Popover Example')),
        body: const SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Button(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  const Button({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Button> createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(),
        onTap: () {
          showPopover(
            context: context,
            bodyBuilder: (context) => const ListItems(),
            onPop: () => print('Popover was popped!'),
            direction: PopoverDirection.top,
            width: 200,
            height: 400,
            arrowHeight: 15,
            arrowWidth: 30,
          );
        },
        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Search Client"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItems extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListItems({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "search"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, Just Wrap the widget where you are calling the popover around `builder` widget and use it's `context`

Hope this solution helps as this helped me in every case where I had the problem using `popover` package!